# swi prolog gives too many solutions

Tags: prolog, dcg

My prolog programm is supposed to return a list of all the variables included in a term. It does work correctly, because my result is a list of all the variables. But now Prolog should stop, instead it continues and gives me the same list of variables eight times. I can't see why it doesn't stop after the solution is found. Can anybody explain to me what's my mistake?

```
variablen(X,[]):-
   number(X).
variablen(X,[X]):-
   atomic(X),
   not(number(X)).

variablen(X+Y,R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(Y+X,R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(X+Y,R):-
   variablen(X,P), variablen(Y,Q), append(P,Q,R).

variablen(X-Y, R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(Y-X, R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(X-Y,R):-
   variablen(X,P), variablen(Y,Q), append(P,Q,R).

variablen(X*Y,R):-
   not(number(X)),atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(Y*X, R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X),R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(X*Y,R):-
   variablen(X,P), variablen(Y,Q), append(P,Q,R).

variablen(X/Y, R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(Y/X, R):-
   not(number(X)), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(X/Y,R):-
   variablen(X,P), variablen(Y,Q), append(P,Q,R).
```

Comment: Yes, that is intended. The problem is now solved because I switched from the Prolog editor (which didn't work) to the ordinary swi-Prolog and now I only get one solution as it was supposed to be. But I don't anderstand what you mean with "here is term_variables/2 as an ISO built-in predicate" ?

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here.

First, `variablen(a,R).` succeeds with `R = [a]`. You said that the list should contain all the variables. So maybe you want to collect all atoms that have for you the meaning of variables.

Second, replace `not/1` which is very implementation specific, by the corresponding ISO built-in `(\+)/1`.

Now, for the redundant solutions found. I will just look at a particular query:

```
?- variablen(a/b,L).
   L = [b,a]
;  L = [a,b]
;  L = [a,b].
```

So there are several ways how the rules apply. I'll just take `/`:

```
variablen(X/Y, R):-
   \+number(X), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(Y/X, R):-
   \+number(X), atomic(X), R1 = [X], variablen(Y,R2), append(R2,R1,R).
variablen(X/Y,R):-
   variablen(X,P), variablen(Y,Q), append(P,Q,R).
```

For `a/b` all three rules apply. Thus your redundancy.

The best solution is to use Definite Clause Grammars, since they handle concatenation much more elegantly:

```
variablen(N) -->
   {functor(N,_,0)}, !,   % rare green cut
   ( {number(N)} ; {atom(N)}, [N] ).
variablen(A+B) -->
   variablen(A),
   variablen(B).
variablen(A-B) -->
   variablen(A),
   variablen(B).
variablen(A*B) -->
   variablen(A),
   variablen(B).
variablen(A/B) -->
   variablen(A),
   variablen(B).
```

Now, you can use it:

```
?- phrase(variablen(a/b),L).
   L = [a,b].
```